# How can I reference a Mobile worker's username in a case list filter in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to create a case list filter in CommCare. Specifically I want to create a filter such that a case property (interviewer_username) is equal to the username of the person who is logged in. I have seen the instructions for how to do this using custom user data and the mobile worker first/last name, but how do you reference the username itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `username` of a user in the case list filter with this syntax:

```
#user/username
```

More information can be found here: https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/User+Case. The username isn't stored in Custom User Data, but rather the User Case.